# i18n nodejs saving data to sequalize db

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, internationalization

I am trying to save the translation json to database using sequelize orm.
Here is my `i18n.config.js` file.

```
 const i18n = require('i18n')
 const translations = require('../db/models/transalations')
 const languages = require('../db/models/languages')

  i18n.configure({
     locales: ['sw', 'en'],
     defaultLocale: 'sw',
     queryParameter: 'lang',
     api: {
        "_": 'translate',
        "_n": 'translateN',
     },
   });

 // Custom translation function using Sequelize
const translate = async (key, locale) => {
locale = i18n.getLocale();
console.log('locale', locale, key);
let lang = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await languages.findOne({ where: { abbreviation: locale } })));
let translation = await translations.findOne({
    where: {
        languageId: await lang.id,
        phrase: key,
    },
});

if (!translation) {
    // If translation doesn't exist in the database, create a new entry
    translation = await translations.create({
        phrase: key,
        translation: key, // You can set a default value if needed
        languageId: await lang.id,
    });
}

return translation.value;
};

// Override the translate function in i18n
i18n.__ = translate;

// Save the translation to the database
const savetranslationsToDatabase = async (key, locale, value) => {
let lang = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await languages.findOne({ where: { abbreviation: locale } })));
let translation = await translations.findOne({
    where: {
        languageId: await lang.id,
        phrase: key,
    },
});

if (translation) {
    // If translation already exists, update its value
    translation.value = value;
    await translation.save();
} else {
    // If translation doesn't exist, create a new entry
    translation = await translations.create({
        phrase: key,
        translation: value,
        languageId: lang.id,
    });
}
};


module.exports = i18n;
```

Here is my handlebars helper function file

```
var register = function (Handlebars) {
  var helpers = {
  phrase: async function (str) {
    if (!str) return str;

    var translation = await i18n.__(str);

  // Synchronous wrapper function to wait for the promise to resolve
    function waitForPromise(promise) {
      if (!promise || typeof promise.then !== 'function') {
        return promise;
      }

      return promise.then(function (result) {
        return result;
      });
    }

    var translated = await waitForPromise(translation);
    console.log('translated', translated);

    if (Handlebars && Handlebars.Utils && Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression) {
      return new Handlebars.SafeString(Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(translated));
    }

    return translated;
   },
// Other helper functions...
  };

 // Register the helpers with Handlebars
   for (var prop in helpers) {
     Handlebars.registerHelper(prop, helpers[prop]);
   }


};

module.exports = register;
```

After implementing this it can store data to the database but seems there issue with retrieving them I get a promise hang

Did my best to solve it I get undefined as translations.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: my question is how do i link it to the tables listed and feed proper sequelize query. so far i have 2 languages how do i link them with those tables instead of a `json` file?